# Update on a small table times out

Tags: sql-server-2008, locking, update

We use Microsoft SQL Server Express Edition with Advanced Services 2008 R2 SP2

We have two locations. Each location has one sql server that serves about 20 client computers. Client computers are connected via wireless network.

Each client computer has to report its state every second by performing a single record update. A web service runs a "select * from" this table every two seconds, and serves web clients with the latest states of all client computers.
The table in question has one row per client computer, 20 rows total. There is a clustered index on the table, on the column used in the where clause of the update. So each client computer updates its own row in the table, and there should be no locking issues.

**The problem** - sometimes updates time out. It happens sporadically about 10 times a day in one location, and about 5 times a day in the other. The first location has 20 client computers, and the second location has 25.
I think that the problem is due to the fact that the table is so small, the update transactions are placing  page locks on the table, and have to wait for each other.

**Question** - will forcing row locks is the right approach to solving this problem, and if not - what should I do to run the updates without timing out?

Below is the update statement - it is very simple:

```
UPDATE dbo.mytable 
SET 
    [col1] = @col1, --more columns here
    [col10] = @col10
WHERE 
    [unique_col] = @unique_value
```

Here is the DDL - I took out the actual col names:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[DCA_CURRENT_DATA_T](

    [col1] [char](12) NOT NULL,
    [col2] [varchar](20) NULL,
    [col3] [char](1) NULL,
    [col4] [int] NULL,
    [col5] [int] NULL,
    [col6] [int] NULL,
    [col7] [char](1) NULL,
    [col8] [int] NULL,
    [col9] [int] NULL,
    [col10] [int] NULL,
    [col11] [int] NULL,
    [col12] [int] NULL,
    [col13] [datetime] NULL,
    [col14] [int] NULL,
    [col15] [int] NULL,
    [col16] [int] NULL,
    [col17] [int] NULL,
    [col18] [int] NULL,
    [col19] [int] NULL,
    [col20] [int] NOT NULL,

PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(

    [col1] ASC

)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, 

ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]


ALTER TABLE [dbo].[DCA_CURRENT_DATA_T] ADD  DEFAULT (0) FOR [col14]
```

Comment: Could you add the table DDL, along with the DDL for any indexes to your question?

Comment: Did you discussed this issue with network team. Its hard to tell correct answer about UPDLOCK but it wont be helpful

Comment: When one of these things is timing out, check sys.dm_exec_requests for something blocking it or a wait that is unexpected. Still, even 20 people trying to update the same row shouldn't take so long to serialize that they time out, unless the application is doing very bad things like opening a transaction and sitting there with it open while the user twiddles their thumbs in the UI...

Comment: we are a small company, and have no network team.

Comment: 20 people are updating **the same table**, but not **the same row**. So I do not see any reason for blocking, even though the sql server obviously has a different opinion. This is a background application that was created solemnly to track status. This application issues one update for one row every second all day long.

Comment: Here is the DDL, I just took the actual col names out.